# Hide divs by class name instead of id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript function that hides div tags from the condition if a checkbox is checked.

following is **JavaScript Code:**

```
function showMeA (div) {

var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("enableA");
var vis = "none";
for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
    if(chboxs[i].checked){
     vis = "block";
        break;
    }
}
 document.getElementById(div).style.display = vis;
}
```

The problem is that function works based on the div's ID. I want to make it work based on the div's class name.

I have tried replacing the `getElementById` part with `getElementsByClassName` but, it doesn't work. Can someone propose an exact change that i need to implement in the function in order for it to work based on the div's class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of DOM Elements. You will need to iterate through this array and set all styles.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName(); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: That is right. I need to iterate through all the elements thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without any Javascript, just with pure CSS and some clever HTML structuring.

```css
.switchme {
  display: none;
  }

#switch:checked ~ .switchme {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="switch" />
<div class="switchme">Switch this div!</div>
<div class="dontswitchme">This div won't be switched.</div>
<ul class="switchme">
  <li>This works without any JS.</li>
  <li>It is based on CSS 3's :checked pseudo selector.</li>
</ul>
<img class="switchme" src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=SwitchMe" alt="" />
```

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep the structure.

Comment: Please bare with me as i am a noob in html and css. So i wanted to use this in a bootstrap modal. I copied the css code you provided in the bootstrap.min.css and the html in the modal window. But for some reason it doesnt work. Do i need to make some specific adjustments in the css file?

Comment: It will always work as long as you have exactly the same html structure as in the example. No additional divs or other stuff dividing the input and the divs, or wrapping either.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `getElementById`, you can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')
```